# Restrict to list Folders under Inbox

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

In here comes every folder details.Now I wanted to Restric it only list "Folders under Inbox"
Actually now i wanted to list folders under inbox.(I created folders under inbox.I don't want to show Outbox,Draft & so..on )

MyCode.

```
private IEnumerable<MAPIFolder> GetAllFolders(Folders folders)
{
    foreach (MAPIFolder f in folders) 
    {
        yield return f;
        foreach (var subfolder in GetAllFolders(f.Folders)) 
        {
            yield return subfolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Button Click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp  = 
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = 
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); 
    // in here i get the error "userd of unassign local variable".
    // without this line code works fine and return all the Folders & 
    // Sub folders.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oPublicFolder = 
        olNS.GetDefaultFolder(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);


    foreach (var f in GetAllFolders(ns.Folders)) 
    {
        //if (f == oPublicFolder) continue;
        if (f.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olMailItem) 
        {
            string ff = f.Name;
            //Some codings here

        }
    }

}
```

This is sometimes a stupid question because sometimes it maybe a pretty simple.But here i ask you from helping hands.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create Application class and get namespace
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi");

    object _missing = Type.Missing;
    ns.Logon(_missing, _missing, false, true);

    // Get Inbox information in objec of type MAPIFolder
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    // Unread emails
    int unread = inbox.UnReadItemCount;

    // Display the subject of emails in the Inbox folder
    foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in inbox.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Wmail.Subject);
    }
```

**FOR FETCHING THE SUB FOLDER NAMES WITHIN INBOX**

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi");

            object _missing = Type.Missing;
            ns.Logon(_missing, _missing, false, true);

            // Get Inbox information in objec of type MAPIFolder
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            // Unread emails
            int unread = inbox.UnReadItemCount;

            // Display the subject of emails in the Inbox folder
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder folds in inbox.Folders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(folds.Name);
            }
```

Comment: Then how to access from inside foreach (var f in GetAllFolders(ns.Folders)) 
    {   ???

Comment: this comes Inbox unread mails know..Here i  want., I created Some folders under Inbox.I want to get that Folder Names.

Comment: Please see this image i wanted to get that folder names > http://i46.tinypic.com/51spis.png